# How can I change my regular expression to read UTF-8?

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I got very far in a script I am working on only to find out it has a problem reading [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters.

I have a contact in Sweden that made a [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) on his machine with some UTF-8 in it and when my script hit that VM it lost its mind, but it was able to read all of the other VMs that are in the "normal" charset.

Anyhow, maybe my code will make more sense.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use utf8;
use Net::OpenSSH;

# Create a hash for storing the options needed by Net::OpenSSH
my %ssh_options = (
    port => '22',
    user => 'root',
    password => 'password'
);

# Create a new Net::OpenSSH object
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('192.168.2.101', %ssh_options);

# Create an array and capture the ESX\ESXi output from the current server
my @getallvms = $ssh->capture('vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms');
shift @getallvms;
# Process data gathered from server
foreach my $vm (@getallvms) {
    # Match ID, NAME
    $vm =~  m/^(?<id> \d+)\s+(?<name> .+?)\s+/xm;
    my $id = "$+{id}";
    my $name = "$+{name}";
    print "$id\n";
    print "$name\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

I have narrowed it down to my regular expression as the problem, because here the raw output from the server before regular expression is applied.

```
416
TEST Box åäö!"''*#
```

And this is what I get after I apply my regular expression

```
416
TEST
```

For some reason the regular expression is not matching, I just don't know why. And the current regular expression in the example is the third attempt at getting it to work.

The FULL line that I am matching looks like this. The way my regular expression was done was because I only need the first two blocks of information, the expression you have wants to copy the entire line.

The code:

```
432    TEST Box åäö!"''*#   [Store] TEST Box +w6XDpMO2IQ-_''_+Iw/TEST Box +w6XDpMO2IQ _''_+Iw.vmx   slesGuest    vmx-04
```

Comment: Provide the output of `use Devel::Peek; Dump $vm;` for the `$vm` that is failing your intended treatment.

Comment: This is a debugging tool for strings - your `print`-ed data is not enough. It enables programmers to understand why exactly the regex fails instead of the wild mass guessing exhibited below.

Comment: I tried adding the module with CPAN and it fails, saying I don't have the right version of perl, I am running on 5.10.1 and says I need 5.13.9 I think, I know at least it said I need 5.13.

Comment: YDIW - there is no need to additionally install `Devel::Peek`, it comes with core Perl since version 5.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subpattern

```
(?<name> .+?)\s+
```

in your regular expression means “match and remember one or more non-newline characters, but stop as soon as you find whitespace,” so `$name` contains `TEST` because the pattern stopped matching when it saw the space just before `Box`.

The [VI Toolkit wiki](http://www.vi-toolkit.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) gives an [example](http://www.vi-toolkit.com/wiki/index.php/Vmsvc/getallvms) of the getallvms subcommand's output:

```
# vmware-vim-cmd -H 10.10.10.10 -U root -P password /vmsvc/getallvms
Vmid    Name               File                 Guest OS       Version   Annotation
64     bartPE    [store] BartPE/BartPE.vmx     winXPProGuest     vmx-04
96     trustix   [store] Trustix/Trustix.vmx   otherLinuxGuest   vmx-04
```

The case is slightly different from the example in your question, but it appears that we can look for `[store]` as a bumper for the match:

```
/^(?<id> \d+) \s+ (?<name> .+?) \s+ \[store]/mix
```

The non-greedy [quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) `+?` means match one or more of something, but the match wants to hand control to the rest of the pattern as quickly as possible. Remember that `[` has a special meaning in regular expressions, but the pattern `\[` matches a literal rather than introducing a character class.

I think of this technique as bookending or tacking-and-stretching. If you want to extract a chunk of text that's difficult to characterize, look for surrounding features that are easy to match—often as simple as `^` or `$`. Then use a stretchy pattern to grab everything in between, usually `(.+)` or `(.+?)`. Read the [“Quantifiers” section of the perlre documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) for an explanation of your many options.

This fixes the immediate problem, and you can also add polish in a few areas.

Do not use `$1`, `$2`, and friends unconditionally! Always test that the pattern matches before using capture variables. For example

```
if (/(foo|bar|baz)/) {
  print "got $1\n";
}
else {
  print "no match\n";
}
```

An unprotected `print $1` can produce surprising results that are tough to debug.

Judicious use of Perl's defaults can help emphasize the computation and lets the mechanism fade into the background. Dropping `$vm` in favor of `$_` as the implicit loop variable and implicit match target makes for a nicer result.

Your comments merely translate from Perl to English. The most helpful comments explain the *why*, not the what. Also keep in mind Rob Pike's [advice on commenting](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html):

> If your code needs a comment to be understood, it would be better to rewrite it so it's easier to understand.

In the assignments from [`%+`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25%2b), the quotes don't do anything useful. The values are already strings, so remove the quotes.

```
my $id   = $+{id};
my $name = $+{name};
```

Below is a modified version of your code that captures everything after the number but before `[store]` into `$name`. The [utf8 pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) declares that your *source code*—not, as with a common mistake, your input—contains UTF-8. The test below simulates with a canned `echo` the output from `vim-cmd` on the Swedish VM.

As Tom suggested, I use the [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module to decode the output that arrives through the SSH connection and encode it for benefit of the local host before printing it out.

The [perlunifaq](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perlunifaq.pod) documentation advises decoding external data into Perl's internal format and then encoding any output just before it's written. I assume that the value returned from `$ssh->capture(...)` uses UTF-8 encoding, that is, that the remote host is sending UTF-8. We see the expected result because I'm running a modern distribution of Linux and ssh-ing back to it, but in the wild, you may be dealing with some other encoding.

You're able to get away with skipping the calls to `decode` and `encode` because Perl's internal format happens to match those of the hosts you're using. In general, however, cutting corners can get you into trouble:

- [What if I don't decode?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#What-if-I-don%27t-decode%3f)
- [What if I don't encode?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#What-if-I-don%27t-encode%3f)

Finally, the code!

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use Encode;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my %ssh_options = ();
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('localhost', %ssh_options);

# Create an array and capture the ESX\ESXi output from the current server
#my @getallvms = $ssh->capture('vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms');
my @getallvms = $ssh->capture(<<EOEcho);
echo -e 'JUNK\n416 TEST Box åäö!"'\\'\\''*#    [Store] TEST Box +w6XDpMO2IQ-_''_+Iw/TEST Box +w6XDpMO2IQ _''_+Iw.vmx   slesGuest    vmx-04'
EOEcho
shift @getallvms;

for (@getallvms) {
  $_ = decode "utf8", $_, Encode::FB_CROAK;

  if (/^(?<id> \d+) \s+ (?<name> .+?) \s+ \[store]/mix) {
    my $id   = $+{id};
    my $name = $+{name};
    print encode("utf8", $id),   "\n",
          encode("utf8", $name), "\n",
          "\n";
  }
  else {
    print "no match\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
416
TEST Box åäö!"''*#
```

Comment: Wow is all I can say for starters. Second, I WAS eventually going to go back and fix the errors where I just "assumed" the regex matched. I am on my 9th revision of this script and it gets better everytime. I will test your modifications but I have to recreate that VM as I deleted because it was causing my script to stop.

Comment: Greg, how come you have `use utf8` in the source but I see no non-ASCII? Future-proofing? Also: I don’t think it changes your answer, but it bothers me that he doesn’t set the encoding anywhere; the `Net::OpenSSH` module apparently makes no allowances for such. He *could* use `binmode` on the returned handle if he were using one of that class’s many other methods that return such, but the simple `capture` method doesn’t. So I think he needs to use `Encode` here. If it’s non‐ASCII non–UTF‑8, at least it will fail hard on malformed input.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the suggestions, Tom. Aren't å, ä, and ö non-ASCII? See my updated answer.

Comment: Greg, the problem with å, ä, and ö  is that they are overlap with ISO 8859-1, so they make me nervous. I grant you that "\xE5\xE4\xF6" as three bytes is not valid UTF-8, but it’s just a general uneasiness.

Comment: Interesting... After reading the edits you made to your answer, the regex that you have at the top of the answer caught my eye. When I use the expression and zero in on the "bumper" that is the [ ] 's. it works perfect with no use of any UTF encode or decode. So far this is exactly what I need and as far as I am concerned problem solved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the string you work on is UTF-8 and Net::OpenSSH doesn't (and hence doesn't mark it as such), you can convert it to an internal representation Perl can work on with one of:

```
use Encode;
decode_utf8( $in_place );
$decoded = decode_utf8( $raw );
```

Comment: well that is the problem, not all of the machine names are encoded in UTF8 just this specific example because I had asked him to create a VM that was very odd to test if my script still worked. this is a very extreme circumstance so I would worry that your solution would break the other 9 VMs that do work and then the one encoded in UTF8 would be the only one working.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? What's the encoding for the other VMs? If it's ASCII, it's a subset of UTF-8 so it ought to work anyway.

Comment: Very true, to be honest I don't know what character set it uses. I assume Unicode being that the base OS for the VMM is a linux build.

Answer (score 3):

So you have make sure, that Perl understand those names as UTF-8 encoded strings. So far I don't think it has. A comprehensive overview [about UTF-8 in Perl](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Unicode_UTF-8).

You can test your strings unicodeness with [`Encode::is_utf8`](http://p3rl.org/Encode#Messing_with_Perl%27s_Internals) and decode them with [`Encode::decode('UTF-8', $your_string)`](http://p3rl.org/Encode#PERL_ENCODING_API).

UTF-8 is pretty messy still in Perl, IMHO. You must have pretty patient with it.

To print UTF-8 strings out in pretty way, you should use something like that in your script:

```
BEGIN {
   binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
   binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');  # Error messages
}
```

If you got Perl understand your UTF-8 names, you could regex them properly too.

Comment: I looked at the link you gave me and I think I have come to my answer. My script is mainly intended for being used in english with standard unicode / ASCII so based on what I am reading I will just now add support for UTF8 it seems like it is a bit too hackish.

Answer (score 3):

[Recent Net::OpenSSH releases](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.51_10/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) have native support for charset encoding/decoding in capture methods:

```
my @getallvms = $ssh->capture({stream_encoding => 'utf8'},
                              'vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms');
```